# Activate a link via MySQL

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I need to create a way to "activate" a link on a page, based on an external trigger.

I've created a page that "should" query every 5sec (via jQuery) an external .php that check a specific table in a db.

Everything works fine on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(fetchdata,5000);
    fetchdata();
});
function fetchdata(){
   $.ajax({
      url: '/get_quiz.php?stanzaid=1',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(response){
      // Perform operation on the return value
      if (quiz > 0) { ... }
[...]
```

Now I know that usually setInterval is not the best way to make things, but since this is for a local app (I expect maximum 10 users each time) it should work.

Is there a better way to do it?*emphasized text*

Comment: You can do like this https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/

Comment: @Amanjot Kaur , that is just interval with counter.

Comment: Look into WebSocket API.